# Detect wrongly typeset non-sentence-ending period

Tags: spacing, typography

Is there any way to extremely increase the spacing after sentence-ending periods in order to (visually) verify that all non-sentence-ending periods are correctly treated using `\` and `\@`? Thanks.

Comment: `\xspaceskip=1cm`?

Comment: Standard tools such as [chktex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chktex) and [lacheck](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lacheck) can also help with this.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Including many false positives and true negatives due to non-perfect regexes used for such checks.

Comment: @ivankokan Agreed - but they both detect the two errors in your example code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength\xspaceskip{1cm}
\begin{document}

this is a sentence. This is Foo. is short for FooBar. and that should have been a comma.
This is not XML\@. And this was not written by Dr.\ Carlisle.
What happens after a semicolon; or a question mark?
This is Foo, followed by a comma.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add this to your example: "This is not XML\@. And this was not written by Dr.\ Carlisle."  You haven't exhausted the possibilities.

Comment: I definitely need to sit down and read TeXbook properly! Is there any change to add a box, in some color maybe?

Comment: @ivankokan not in classic tex, in luatex yes (well of course in classic tex it is always possible to do something, but the macros would be sufficiently complicated they would likely clash with many packages and be more trouble than worth for a debugging aid)

Comment: @barbarabeeton you are free to edit. And I know you are itching to add some commas and semicolons:-)

Comment: @barbarabeeton OK :-)

Comment: @barbarabeeton done